# How to fix "Invalid use of '.','!', or '()' in query expression" in Visual Studio Query Builder

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ms-access

I have run this query successfully in msaccess the difference being the use of the `Nz()` function instead of `coalesce()` function.On trying to run it on VS Query Builder, the error in the title keeps preventing execution.The query is

```
SELECT t.id AS Member,
   coalesce((SELECT t1.offering FROM list as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Jan'),'x') AS Jan,
   coalesce((SELECT t1.offering FROM list as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Feb'),'x') AS Feb, 
   coalesce((SELECT t1.offering FROM list as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Mar'),'x') AS Mar,
   coalesce((SELECT t1.offering FROM list as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Apr'),'x') AS Apr
FROM list AS t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've correctly understood your data (based only on assumptions gleaned from your query), rather than using correlated subqueries for each month, I would suggest something along the lines of the following:

```
select 
    t.id as member,
    nz(max(iif(t.check_month = 'Jan', t.offering)),'x') as Jan,
    nz(max(iif(t.check_month = 'Feb', t.offering)),'x') as Feb,
    nz(max(iif(t.check_month = 'Mar', t.offering)),'x') as Mar,
    nz(max(iif(t.check_month = 'Apr', t.offering)),'x') as Apr
from
    list t
group by 
    t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your missing the join for table 't1'

I added a record to your data for testing nulls...

```
[Id], [offering], [check_month]
(1,Null,'Jul'),
(1,'offer1','Jan'),
(1,'offer2','Feb'),
(1,'offer3','Mar'),
(1,'offer4','Apr')
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.id AS Member,
   nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM vlist as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Jan'),'x') AS Jan,
   nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM vlist as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Feb'),'x') AS Feb, 
   nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM vlist as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Mar'),'x') AS Mar,
   nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM vlist as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Apr'),'x') AS Apr,
      nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM vlist as t1 where t1.id =  t.id and t1.check_month='Jul'),'x') AS Jul
FROM vlist AS t Left Join
     vlist t1 On t1.Id = t.Id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Result:

```
Member  Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     Jul
1       offer1  offer2  offer3  offer4  x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Nz((SELECT t1.offering FROM list as t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.check_month = 'Jan'),'x') AS Jan,
```

Comment: It doesn't work.I get `Error in list of function arguments:SELECT not recognized`